# Chart.js Globally Formatted Number Labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

All I want to do is set a simple Global Option that formats numbers with commas for Y AXIS and Tooltips. I have tried a million examples and I can not get this to work.

Version: Chart.js/2.2.2

I would like to format all numbers with commas for Y axis and tooltip values using a simple global option. The reason why this would be easier using global is that I am generating and dynamically sending in the JSON data and adding more options to that would be a pain, dynamically when all the numbers need to just behave the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**After talking to the developer I have a really nice global method for setting y axis and tooltip number formatting. I hope this can help someone else too!**

You can definitely use global options to control that.

For instance, here's how you would update so that all linear scales (the default Y axis) will format using dollar signs and nice numbers

```
Chart.scaleService.updateScaleDefaults('linear', {
  ticks: {
    callback: function(tick) {
      return '$' + tick.toLocaleString();
    }
  }
});
```

Here's how you could also do the same for a tooltip

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.callbacks.label = function(tooltipItem, data) {
  var dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
  var datasetLabel = dataset.label || '';
  return datasetLabel + ": $" + dataset.data[tooltipItem.index].toLocaleString();
};
```

**Then I asked about including simple flags for formatting within the axes and dataset settings:**

I've hesitated to push to include these in the core because there are so many different options and trying to support each and every one would dramatically increase the size of the already large library. It may make sense to encourage someone to create a library of formatters that essentially automates the creation of these functions to speed up development.

**References:**

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3294#issuecomment-246532871
https://jsfiddle.net/ChrisGo/k4Lxncvm/

Comment: Nice. One minor bug, in the last line of the second code you should take the `y` from the data, i.e.:
`return datasetLabel + ": $" + dataset.data[tooltipItem.index].y.toLocaleString();`